# javascript run function as a string

Tags: javascript

I am developing for an API that required the code to be passed to it as a string, for it to run, like this:

```
var api = [API ID],
    code = "alert('some text')";

api.evalScript(code);
```

But I have a lot of code to pass at the same time, how can I pass an entire function like that?

```
    var api = [API ID];

    function my_code(){
       alert('one');
       alert('two');
       alert('three');
    }

    api.evalScript(my_code());
```

This doesn't work

Comment: "API that required the code to be passed to it as a string" --- that's a terrible idea. Why do you need that?

Comment: @zerkms Well, its not really up to me to choose which API's I must use ;)

Comment: can't you just take function references? what is the end game?

Comment: In your second case you don't have a string containing code, so you wouldn't use `evalScript` at all. Did you just pick a bad example? Could you provide a better one?

Comment: @GEspinha okay. I though it's you who implement it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing the code as a function, not a string.

```
var my_code = "alert('one');\n" +
              "alert('two');\n" + 
              "alert('three');"


api.evalScript(my_code);
```

*the newlines are optional*

Comment: '\n' does not work like you think it does in js, String.fromCharCode(13) is what you have to do.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(13)` is `"\r"`, not `"\n"`. For `"\n"` you'd use `String.fromCharCode(10)`. That said, `\r` and `\n` both work, so there's no reason to resort to `fromCharCode()`.

Answer (score 1):

take your function and append an empty string like this:

```
my_code += '';
```

Will coerce it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the security implications here.

So evalScript probably wants a strings, where you're trying to eval a function and that isn't going to work so well.

Let's talk about how to easily concat a large string in JS.

```
var myCode = [
   'alert("one");',
   'alert("two");',
   'alert("three");'
].join('');

api.evalScript(myCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're passing code to the API that will be executed at some later point that the API determines, and you have a function that you want the API to execute, you can probably just pass `"mycode()"` to the API.

However, if you intend the code to be executed immediately, it doesn't appear that there's any reason to use the API at all, so you could just call `my_code()` directly.